# How to declare empty list and then add string in scala?

Tags: scala

I have code like this:

```
val dm  = List[String]()
val dk = List[Map[String,Object]]()

.....

dm.add("text")
dk.add(Map("1" -> "ok"))
```

but it throws runtime java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

I need to declare empty list or empty maps and some where later in the code need to fill them.

Comment: What makes you think there is an `add` operation on `List`?

Comment: If you want to use the add operation, you would have to declare an ArrayList. Vals in scala are essentially immutable, so you can't add to them.

Comment: iirc val is more like final, you can add to them if you use the mutable Collections. e.g. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html

Comment: I thought add is valid method because compiler did not give error. Only runtime exception. So in that how do I create lists and add to them?

Comment: @rjc Which version of scala are you using ? Mine (2.9.0) gives me a compile error.

Comment: Did you import `scala.collection.JavaConversions`? If you did, you are seeing the very reason why I recommend `JavaConverters` instead: `dm` and `dk` are being converted into a Java collection, and then the `add` method called on that collection. Worse, `dm` and `dk` are not being modified, even if you did not get an error. And, by the way, the error is that `1 -> "ok"` is `Map[Int,String]`, not `Map[String, Object]`.

Comment: @Debilski Don't be smug like that. Just tell him that Scala Lists are immutable. That is unless he imported the mutable version.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Scala lists are immutable by default. You cannot "add" an element, but you can form a new list by appending the new element in front. Since it is a *new* list, you need to reassign the reference (so you can't use a val).

```
var dm  = List[String]()
var dk = List[Map[String,AnyRef]]()

.....

dm = "text" :: dm
dk = Map(1 -> "ok") :: dk
```

The operator `::` creates the new list. You can also use the shorter syntax:

```
dm ::= "text" 
dk ::= Map(1 -> "ok")
```

**NB:** In scala don't use the type `Object` but `Any`, `AnyRef` or `AnyVal`.

Comment: Very good answer but can you tell if I declare list like in your answer, are they of type scala.collections.mutable or immutable type? REPL did not make this clear.

Comment: By default. If you import nothing. `List` is immutable. That's the recommended one for most usage.

Comment: @rjc Scala doesn't have a `mutable.List` -- `List` is a concrete type, of which the only implementation is immutable. There are immutable classes such as `LinkedList` and `DoubleLinkedList`, which are mostly helper classes. The Scala equivalent of Java's `ArrayList` is `ArrayBuffer`, and the equivalent of Java's `LinkedList` is `ListBuffer`. The trait that corresponds to Java's `List` is `Seq` -- of which there is `collection.Seq` and, extending it, `collection.immutable.Seq` and `collection.mutable.Seq`.

Comment: @paradigmatic is there a difference between `::=` and `+=` ?

Comment: @Mahdi There may be a difference. On lists only `::` is defined so `+=` will not work. On other collection (not in standard lib): If `::=` or `+=` are implemented, the implementation will be used. Else, the compiler will turn `x::=y` into `x = y::x` and `x+=y` inro `x=x+y`. In the second case, they are the same if the implementation of `::` is the same as the implementation of `+`...

Answer (score 19):

If you need to mutate stuff, use `ArrayBuffer` or `LinkedBuffer` instead. However, it would be better to address this statement:

> I need to declare empty list or empty
>   maps and some where later in the code
>   need to fill them.

Instead of doing that, fill the list with code that returns the elements. There are many ways of doing that, and I'll give some examples:

```
// Fill a list with the results of calls to a method
val l = List.fill(50)(scala.util.Random.nextInt)

// Fill a list with the results of calls to a method until you get something different
val l = Stream.continually(scala.util.Random.nextInt).takeWhile(x => x > 0).toList

// Fill a list based on its index
val l = List.tabulate(5)(x => x * 2)

// Fill a list of 10 elements based on computations made on the previous element
val l = List.iterate(1, 10)(x => x * 2)

// Fill a list based on computations made on previous element, until you get something
val l = Stream.iterate(0)(x => x * 2 + 1).takeWhile(x => x < 1000).toList

// Fill list based on input from a file
val l = (for (line <- scala.io.Source.fromFile("filename.txt").getLines) yield line.length).toList
```

Answer (score 14):

As everyone already mentioned, this is not the best way of using lists in Scala...

```
scala> val list = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
list: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String] = MutableList()

scala> list += "hello"
res0: list.type = MutableList(hello)

scala> list += "world"
res1: list.type = MutableList(hello, world)

scala> list mkString " "
res2: String = hello world
```

Comment: Can you tell if your list are declared like in your answer, will it give better runtime performance as opposed to answer by paradigmetic? Assume millions of elements would be added in the list.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. I would recommend to start with an immutable one as @paradigmatic has suggested. The complexity of adding an element to an immutable list like this: `list ::= "text"` is O(1) which is constant and the best you can do.

Comment: rjc: cons of immutable lists is O(1); however, what really matters is your access pattern as far as efficiency is concerned. For example, if order matters and you must build the list by appending, Vector is a better (immutable) choice.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in an above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557304/1461060), the [Scala List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is an immutable collection. You can create an empty list with **`.empty[A]`**. Then you can use a method [`:+`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#::(x:A):List[A]) , [`+:`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#::(x:A):List[A]) or [`::`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#::(x:A):List[A]) in order to add element to the list.

```
scala> val strList = List.empty[String]
strList: List[String] = List()

scala> strList:+ "Text"
res3: List[String] = List(Text)

scala> val mapList = List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
mapList: List[Map[String,Any]] = List()

scala> mapList :+ Map("1" -> "ok")
res4: List[Map[String,Any]] = List(Map(1 -> ok))
```

Answer (score 2):

Per default collections in scala are immutable, so you have a + method which returns a new list with the element added to it.
If you really need something like an add method you need a mutable collection, e.g. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html which has a += method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ListBuffers in scala to create empty list and add strings later because ListBuffers are mutable. Also all the List functions are available for the ListBuffers in scala.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer 

val dm = ListBuffer[String]()
dm: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
dm += "text1"
dm += "text2"
dm = ListBuffer(text1, text2)
```

if you want you can convert this to a list by using .toList

Answer (score 0):

In your case I use: `val dm = ListBuffer[String]()` and `val dk = ListBuffer[Map[String,anyRef]]()`