# Making more "functional" code in Scala to use immutable collections

Tags: scala, data-structures, functional-programming

I'm porting an algorithm from Java to Scala that does a range search on a [VP Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantage-point_tree).  Briefly, the nodes in the tree have coordinates in space and a radius: nodes within that radius can be found on the left subtree, whilst nodes outside that radius are found on the right subtree.  A range search attempts to find all objects in the tree within a specified distance to a query object.

In Java I passed the function an arraylist in which it accumulated results, possibly recursing down one of either or both subtrees.  Here's a straight port into Scala:

```
def search(node: VPNode[TPoint, TObject], query: TPoint, radius: Double,
    results: collection.mutable.Set[TObject]) {

  var dist = distance(query, node.point)

  if (dist < radius)
    results += node.obj

  if (node.left != null && dist <= radius + node.radius)
    search(node.left, query, radius, results)

  if (node.right != null && dist >= radius + node.radius)
    search(node.right, query, radius, results)
}
```

Scala's default collection types are immutable, and I was thinking it was a bit annoying having to type `collection.mutable.` all the time, so I started looking into it.  It seems to be recommended that using the immutable collections are nearly always fine: I'm using this code to do millions of lookups though, and it seems to me that copying and concatenating the results array would slow it down.

Answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559283/632636) for example suggest that the problem needs to be approached more 'functionally'.

So, what should I do to solve this problem in a more Scala-esque fashion?  Ideally I'd like it to be as fast as the Java version, but I'm interested in solutions regardless (and can always profile them to see if it makes much difference).

Note, I only just started learning Scala (figured I may as well cut my teeth on something useful) but I'm not new to functional programming, having used Haskell before (although I don't think I'm that good at it!).

Comment: Why do you use an `ArrayList` in Java but a `Set` in Scala? It would be more similar to use `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: I was actually using a Set in Java too, I just said the wrong thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you would get good performance by using the standard immutable `List`. All `search` does is to check one node at a time and append the current element if it meets some criteria, then do a double recursion. So you can use an immutable accumulator:

```
def search(node: VPNode[TPoint, TObject], query: TPoint, radius: Double,
    acc: List[TObject] = Nil): List[TObject] = {

  val dist = distance(query, node.point)
  val mid = if (dist < radius) node.obj :: acc else acc

  val midLeft =
    if (node.left != null && dist <= radius + node.radius)
      search(node.left, query, radius, mid)
    else mid

  if (node.right != null && dist >= radius + node.radius)
    search(node.right, query, radius, midLeft)
  else midLeft
}
```

As far as I can see this only prepends to the beginning of the accumulator and should be fast.

Note that I think it's fine to use a mutable collection internally and return an immutable one to the caller:

```
def search(node: VPNode[TPoint, TObject], query: TPoint, radius: Double): Vector[TObject] = {
  import collection.immutable.{VectorBuilder => Builder}
  def rec(n: VPNode[TPoint, TObject], acc: Builder[TObject]): Builder[TObject] = {
    val dist = distance(query, node.point)
    val mid = if (dist < radius) acc += node.obj
    if (node.left != null && dist <= radius + node.radius) rec(node.left, acc)
    if (node.right != null && dist >= radius + node.radius) rec(node.right, acc)
    acc
  }
  rec(node, new Builder()).result
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could do some of this stuff.  I think if it's just appending to the front then an immutable collection might be the way forward.

Comment: @stewartml, if you need to use `Set`, you can use immutable set and do `acc + node.obj`. If you end up performing some profiling/benchmarking, let me know how it compared to the Java version.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I would consider a more functional approach:

```
val emptySet = Set[TObject]()

def search(node: VPNode[TPoint, TObject], query: TPoint, radius: Double): Set[TObject] = {
  val dist = distance(query, node.point)

  val left = Option(node.left) // avoid nulls
    .filter(_ => dist <= radius + node.radius) // do nothing if predicate fails
    .fold(emptySet)(l => search(l, query, radius)) // continue your search

  val right = Option(node.right)
    .filter(_ => dist >= radius + node.radius)
    .fold(emptySet)(r => search(r, query, radius))

  left ++ right ++ (if (dist < radius) Set(node.obj) else emptySet)
}
```

Instead of passing around your `mutable.Set` to each `search` function, the `search` function returns a `Set[TObject]` which it then concatenates onto other sets. If you were to build up the function calls, it would look like each node of your tree was being concatenated with each other (assuming they were in your radius).

From an efficiency perspective, this is probably not as efficient as the mutable version. Using a `List` instead of a `Set` would probably be better, and then you can convert the final `List` to a `Set` when you're done (though still probably not as fasts as the mutable version).

**UPDATE**
To answer your question about the benefits:

1. Determinism - Since it's immutable you're always guaranteed the same results when calling this function with the same paramaters. With that said, you're original version should be deterministic, you just don't know who else is modifiying your results, though that's probably not much of an issue.
2. Hard to read? - I think that's more a matter of opinion and experience in different styles of programming. I found your version hard to read because you don't return any value from the function and you have multiple if statements. I agree that at first `Option`/`filter`/`fold` can look a bit strange, but after you start using them for awhile (just like anything) it becomes easy to read. I would compare this to being able to read LINQ in .NET.
3. Performance - Using @huynhjl's answer using a `List` you should get equal if not better performance from your original version. It appears that you don't really need to use `Set` which has the overhead of making sure everything in the set is unique.
4. Garbage Collection - In the purely functional version you're creating new objects quickly and also dropping them quickly which means they most likely will not survive past the GC's first generation. This is important because moving objects between generations is what forces a GC pause. In the mutable version, you're passing around a reference to the original collection which hangs around longer and may get compacted to the next generation. This isn't exactly the greatest example because your mutable version is probably not that long lived and who knows what you want to do with the return object (maybe keep it around for awhile). In the mutable version you'll most likely end up with a second gen collection pointing to second gen objects, while the immutable version you'll end up with a first gen collection pointing to second gen objects. Cleaning up the immutable version will be much faster and pause-less (again, this is making some broad assumptions and generalizations about the usage of your objects and what the GC is doing, your mileage may vary).
5. Parallelism - The functional version can be easily parallelized, while the mutable version cannot. Depending on the size of your tree this probably isn't a big issue.

Since you seem fairly interested, I would recommend reading [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/). It goes over all of these basics in what I think is a great way for beginners.

Comment: I started to write an answer and then realized it was the same as yours modulo the `Option`/`filter`/`fold`, which obscured that fact, so I went for something else in my answer. Maybe the null avoidance should be done in `VPNode` instead.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  It took me a minute to figure out what was going on there, I need to get to grips with this functional paradigm!  Slight aside: if it's more difficult to read (debatably) and slower, what are the benefits of writing it that way?

Comment: @huynhjl I'm assuming that he's using a java library that uses null, otherwise yes it would be great to have the null avoidance in `VPNode`. Using scala's `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` you could easily `fold` over the tree or implement some custom `fold` operation as well. As a side note, I like your version with the `List` accumulator. I started briefly with that version, but ended up going an alternate route.

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for the book recommendation.  Parallelisation is something that I'll be looking into, so good point about that.