# How to return an empty List when nothing found

Tags: scala, selenium

I wonder how to return an empty `List` when i try to find some `WebElement` but nothing found.
Of course i want to avoid crash so this is what i have try:

```
def getList(): List[WebElement] = {

    try {
      driver.fineElements(By.xpath("bla bla))
    }catch{
      case e: TimeoutException => // What should i put here ???
    }
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6557312/4985572 check it out, maby it helps you

Comment: I don't think this a solution for what i asked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver - Test if element is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present)

Comment: Duplicates this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6521834/21755 even more closely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriver: check if an element exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists)

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong.. it doesn't even work. Please accept Mobrockers answer.

Comment: Well, it works, in that there isn't an exception so there's no need to catch one. I'd delete it, though, as it doesn't really address the question, except that since it's accepted i can't :(.

Comment: I've flagged my answer for a moderator to delete

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

I didn't notice you're using scala and not java, apologies, however it works the same in Scala. From the scala docs:

> The findAll method returns an immutable IndexedSeq of all matching elements. If no elements match the query, findAll returns an empty IndexedSeq.

It *already* returns an empty list if no elements are found, and will **not** cause an exception.

The scala findAll method will do the same.

If you are not using scalatest but rather the Java selenium package, the same is still true. findElements will return an empty list when no elements are found and will never ever throw a TimeoutException.

Comment: The OP isn't using `findAll`

Comment: There is no fineElement in selenium... From what I can gather from the docs, scala can use either findElements or findAll, they're the same. In both cases it will return an empty list and this try catch exception will **never** work as findElements or findAll do not throw an exception..

Comment: OK, gotcha. Since the OP specifies that `getList` returns a `List[WebElement]` we can assume he's using `findElements`, not `findElement`. So it will return an empty list as you say

Comment: It's kinda silly to create a function for this... it's a one-liner.